# SQL Query - How to find a field with two or more same characters in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server DB and I would like to write query which will look for a fields with two or more slashes in it, lets say we have these rows:

```
1. abc/def/g
2. abcd/efg
3. a/b/c/d/e/f/g
```

So it should return 1st and 3rd row! What is the easiest way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I would like to write query" - so, have you already started to write it? Can you show some of your efforts and specify problems you've faced? Also - it is better to specify what exactly DBMS you have, because `sql` is very broad concept.

Comment: Which DBMS? Sql Server Mysql etc. PS this could be a very expensive query...

Comment: I am assuming that you are using a RDBMS. You can try `select * from [table name] where [column name of above data] like '%/%/%';`. This is a general syntax, may change depending upon your DBMS.

Comment: You can accept it as an answer than... :)

Comment: @PrerakSola I'm not sure how to accept it form comments area to be honest!